# Cannot find definition when trying to use Authentication Builder's AddTwitter()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter, oauth-2.0

When trying to add a Twitter external sign-in to my SPA ASP.NET application following this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/twitter-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.0) I encountered an error:

```
'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddTwitter' and no accessible extension method 'AddTwitter' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is referring to line 36 of my Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication().AddTwitter(twitterOptions =>
        {
            twitterOptions.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerAPIKey"];
            twitterOptions.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
        });

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }
```

How can I rectify this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter/) package to the project.

They forgot to put this in the documentation. They did for Facebook.